# Change the arguments in a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a RabbitMQ queue that was originally declared like this:

```
var result = _channel.QueueDeclare("NewQueue", true, false, false, null);
```

And I'm trying to add a dead letter exchange, so I've changed the code to this:

```
_channel.ExchangeDeclare("dl.exchange", "direct");
Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "x-dead-letter-exchange", "dl.exchange" }
};            

var result = _channel.QueueDeclare("NewQueue", true, false, false, args);
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> Exception thrown:
>   'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException' in
>   RabbitMQ.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP
>   close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED -
>   inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'NewQueue' in
>   vhost '/': received the value 'dl.exchange' of type 'longstr' but
>   current is none", classId=50, methodId=10, cause=

The error seems pretty self explanatory, and if I delete the queue, when I re-create it, I don't get the error, but my question is: is there a way to make this change without deleting the queue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, by default you have to delete the queue and recreate it.

but you can use the policy:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy DLX "NewQueue" '{"dead-letter-exchange":"my-dlx"}' --apply-to queues
```

In this way you can add or remove queue `args` without delete it.

[Read here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for more detail.

> Configuration using policy
>
> To specify a DLX using policy, add the key "dead-letter-exchange" to a
>   policy definition. 
>   Similarly, an explicit routing key can be specified by adding the key
>   "dead-letter-routing-key" to the policy.
>
> Policies can also be defined using the management plugin, see the
>   policy documentation for more details.

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. The message isn't routed, and only doing so via the "x-dead-letter-exchange" works